# Joomla MooTools error

Tags: mootools

I am using joomla 1.5.20 which contains mootols files i am getting error

```
Error: ($(b) || document).getElements is not a function
Source File: http://sitename/plugins/system/mtupgrade/mootools.js
Line: 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want more information about your bug you can download Firebug. That's a firefox plugin which gives you more info about javascript errors.

Firebug: https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/firebug/

Comment: I have firebug it shows ($(b) || document).getElements is not a function
Native(a=".jamod", b=undefined)mootools.js (line 1)
(?)(e=undefined)ja.rightcol.js (line 59)
Native()mootools.js (line 1)
[Break On This Error] var MooTools={version:"1.2.4",build:"0..."::")[1]);b.set("title","")}})}})})();

Comment: I have also get error while i am submitting joomla eventlist form "Error: $(form.title).getValue is not a function"

Comment: er, `getValue()` is a mootools 1.1x method that got deprecated in 1.2+ - what are you trying to do? sounds like you have referenced a new version of mootools and still have old .js files lying around.